# Convergent subsequences of sequences whose difference tends to zero

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Suppose we have two sequences $p, q:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow K$, where $K$ is a compact set and $K \subset \mathbb{R}$, such that $|p_n - q_n|\rightarrow 0$. Since $K$ is compact, there are $p'_n, q'
_n$ convergent subsequences of $p, q$ such that their limit are in $K$. Is it true that $|p'_n-q'_n|\rightarrow 0$, or in other words, that $\lim_{n\to\infty}p'_n = \lim_{n\to\infty}q'_n$?

Answer (score 0):

Since $K$ is a compact set $K \subset \mathbb R$ that means that $K$ is closed and bounded. Now, since $|p_n - q_n| \to 0$ this essentialy means that $p_n$ can approach $q_n$ infinitely closed and since they are $p,q : \mathbb N \to K$, then we can imply that they are bounded. But by the [Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolzano%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem), each bounded sequence has a convergent subsequence, thus it is true that $|p'_n - q'_n| \to 0$.

Comment: I think that $(p'_n - q'_n)$ is not necessarily a subsequence of $(p-q)$ since the index functions that generate $p', q'$ may be different.

Comment: Note that a subsequence $a_{kn}$ of a sequence $a_n$ contains elements of the sequence $a_n$. Thus, think about $p'_n-q'_n$. In other words, $|p_n - q_n| \to 0$ essentialy means that the sequences can be brought infinitely close. The same wouldn't hold for the subsequences, since they are just elements of the initial, but $K$ being compact plays a big role here, explained above.